# Using Git with a Redmine hosted on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, redmine

I have a question. I am using Redmine for a issue tracking system for my upcoming project and I recently did the install on Heroku and I was wondering if there was a good way to use Git via a github repository to do issue tracking (ie. I can make a commit, do a refs #issue_number and it would associate that commit with the issue I'm tracking). I know there is some way to do it with svn, but we want to use git for the project. I heard that heroku is unable to do Redmine with git from someone since you need a 'bare' and 'minimum' directory? (or something similar to that) Is this true? or is there a guide out there (I've been googling 'git with heroku and redmine' and other variants for the last little bit with no luck) on installing git to associate it with my github repository for my heroku based Redmine?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, you have mentioned that you are using GitHub, Redmine, and Heroku, and want to relate commits to issue numbers within Redmine.

I believe that Heroku will not come into this, but what you want to look at is a post-receive hook for your repository on GitHub.

The best direction I can give you is to follow [this](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) documentation, but select the "Redmine" post-receive hook, and set it up according to the detailed instructions that they provide.

The documentation for the hook explicitly states the following:

> Commits which are related to Redmine issues are detected by matching '#IssueNo' in the commit message (i.e "fixing bug #234" is related to issue #234)

which I believe is the functionality that you are after. Please correct me if I am wrong.